# Перекодировка текста в php

Tags: php

Получаю файл с удаленного сервера с текстом, который отображается, как просто набор символов - Êðèâîíîñû;Ðàéîí Ñòàðîäîðîæñêèé, îáë. Ìèíñêàÿ;Áåëàðóñü...
В редакторе Sublime кириллица исправляется при переходе на win-1251, но мне нужно получить это средствами php. mb_detect_encoding определяет что кракозябры в файле формата utf-8, Sublime - что Western Windows-1252.
Пытаюсь перекодировать iconv и mb_convert_encoding, но возвращаются другие кракозябры или просто знаки вопроса. Понятно, что это можно в редакторе поправить и далее работать с нормальной кодировкой, но у меня автоматическое обновление файла и его парсинг, мне нужна перекодировка средствами php.

```
<?php $str = 'Êðèâîíîñû;Ðàéîí Ñòàðîäîðîæñêèé, îáë. Ìèíñêàÿ;Áåëàðóñü';
//echo mb_detect_encoding($str);  //UTF-8
echo mb_convert_encoding($str, 'Windows-1251', 'UTF-8' );
//echo iconv('UTF-8', 'Windows-1251', $str);
```

Comment: <?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>

Comment: @Isaev, мне не требуются заголовки, я скачиваю файл с текстом, потом делаю парсинг его строк. фишка в том, что данные в другом формате и я не могу их обработать внутри php

Comment: это не utf-8, тебе нужно CP1252 -> CP1251
https://www.artlebedev.ru/decoder/

Comment: Лучше решите не последствия, а изначальную причину — как так вообще получилось, что вы с удалённого сервера получили это, а не нормальный текст?

Comment: @andreymal этот файл я загружаю по ftp с сервера одной транспортной компании. это их локации

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения этой задачи нужно переводить от одной к другой (так как к вам приходит utf-8, она не умещается в 1 байт, происходят танцы с бубном).
Таким способом:

```
$str = 'Êðèâîíîñû;Ðàéîí Ñòàðîäîðîæñêèé, îáë. Ìèíñêàÿ;Áåëàðóñü';
$str = iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252', $str));
echo $str; // Кривоносы;Район Стародорожский, обл. Минская;Беларусь
```